# How to save the state of check box to local storage using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to save the current state of check box and reload it when open the page next time.

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {

    var init = function () {
        $scope.check = $window.localStorage.getItem("app3");
    };

    init();

    $scope.Save = function () {
        $window.localStorage.setItem("app3", $scope.check);
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular-1.4.9.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" ng-model="check" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use jquery with angular.
Attach a ng-model to your input box like so :  and you can access the value of the input in your controller using $scope.check
your local storage setting will be like so :
$window.localStorage.setItem('app3',$scope.check);
Thats it! Kindly go through angular tutorials or their documentation to understand how angular works.

Comment: Do you want to say I need to delete this: ng-checked="SetCheckbox()" ?

Comment: yes remove that and put ng-model="check". If you attach ng-model to an input element. any value entered will create a variable in your controller like $scope.check..

Comment: I did it, but noticed when check box is checked $scope.check is true, but when is unchecked $scope.check is undefined. Is it regular to save undefined to local storage?

Comment: Please take a look at the original post because I've modified the code. But getting saved checked value still doesn't work. What I'm missing?

Comment: I mean I check or uncheck the check box and press "Save". After that I close the page, reopen it and see always unchecked check box.

Comment: you have to get the stored value back by using $scope.check = $window.localStorage.getItem('app3'); in your controller then it will be automatically checked. Kindly upvote / mark as correct if you found my answer useful.

Comment: As you can see up there I did it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I needed to convert the value from locale storage to Boolean. It works now.